# Concerning change in reputation score

Tags: discussion, reputation, accepted-answer

What kind of change in reputation score does happen when I accept an answer , given by me to a question by myself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None, you do not get any reputation for accepting your own answer.

Comment: Uh! so that's the thing